# How to get the median line in bwplot thicker?

Tags: r, lattice

The following code is a minimal (for some value of minimal....) example that uses `lattice` to produce boxplots. But the median line on those boxplot is a) coloured and b) very thin. How to get them to be black and tick?

```
a71<-structure(list(n = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("100", 
"200", "400", "800"), class = "factor"), g = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "0.5", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    cr = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("-0.4", "0", "0.4"), class = "factor"), bias = c(0.0162558992812201, 
    0.138354243932496, 0.0205686041691062, 0.269714433604472, 
    0.381044037439145, 0.0869422119950729, 0.331379037601084, 
    0.686894150152472, 0.0140922903231885, 0.225078933454863, 
    0.554444988164574, 0.076032683077827, 0.335284040888653, 
    0.0630810396519646, 0.358402154233125, 0.260940142571834, 
    0.141353291599136, 0.0220267076189838, 0.242149484071382, 
    0.278319984858078, 0.193105829691662, 0.0259815643559331, 
    0.318504899459259, 0.00277002060524357, 0.212681621053374, 
    0.418358846098857, 0.358916156777489, 0.438248724241505, 
    0.194398889511096, 0.2266870834128, 0.144338808446284, 0.149227951210927, 
    0.268111328952192, 0.123265441389974, 0.0376832357983068, 
    0.0353605481767078, 0.021227873083535, 0.0385614926552725, 
    0.130640111978654, 0.161865326447675, 0.174151298764213, 
    0.292085797406362, 0.198391364913347, 0.0779507859721407, 
    0.0045571464157577, 0.114734038438965, 0.0469613758623325, 
    0.64238405800387, 0.74508519247034, 0.0251182457091362, 0.217835062247358, 
    0.131159910126724, 0.130034859007596, 0.222418419987533, 
    0.0861715693619894, 0.185660520258661, 0.0940670543815277, 
    0.105680179626893, 0.215966730684923, 0.109008340760604, 
    0.0474735195202623, 0.192326789813641, 0.022147195644035, 
    0.277372858009381, 0.237574293593955, 0.123383946121193, 
    0.46406480500022, 0.123698482002945, 0.671442441453945, 0.0406004813894845, 
    0.260472754754191, 0.0151116521560003, 0.0422855023583402, 
    0.0405517218780402, 0.0441583998205882, 0.0958995639409343, 
    0.37588506579263, 0.098494760958735, 0.0928763466294421, 
    0.111205748449328, 0.413083543393392, 0.0138839674143682, 
    0.22407421093074, 0.72309883706409, 0.423231501875638, 0.141932050342199, 
    0.133808548118004, 0.331500621801688, 0.127652280721512, 
    0.132083126730013, 0.261864564503826, 0.208243130464985, 
    0.18657049493156, 0.333701537602998, 0.404884075502013, 0.470789398932934, 
    0.115008599462104, 0.177984001517338, 0.331717679106776, 
    0.0862418839846533), group = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("n", 
"g", "cr", "bias", "group"), row.names = c(8721L, 6970L, 6686L, 
9624L, 352L, 10545L, 7505L, 4216L, 6170L, 3309L, 10429L, 4302L, 
5602L, 5680L, 1530L, 9234L, 5007L, 8004L, 721L, 10038L, 502L, 
4891L, 2946L, 8502L, 622L, 1972L, 2403L, 3383L, 5880L, 1038L, 
4756L, 9506L, 2169L, 1023L, 8506L, 6239L, 7768L, 3221L, 9536L, 
5981L, 1507L, 4883L, 414L, 3117L, 3993L, 1923L, 9143L, 2673L, 
4430L, 9520L, 9363L, 10602L, 95L, 1141L, 9660L, 4285L, 10704L, 
154L, 531L, 6440L, 4876L, 7052L, 4397L, 3375L, 5075L, 1295L, 
2620L, 334L, 9510L, 4690L, 4288L, 3576L, 2248L, 7693L, 8820L, 
8135L, 4026L, 1906L, 10164L, 8616L, 423L, 5290L, 418L, 6486L, 
4485L, 7042L, 955L, 2215L, 9031L, 8049L, 2323L, 1627L, 4212L, 
8689L, 439L, 2590L, 8649L, 5447L, 1957L, 10570L), class = "data.frame")
 library(lattice)
cl<-c('red','green','blue')
mypanel<-function(...){
        panel.bwplot(...,pch="|",col="black",cex=4,fill=cl)
}
o1<-bwplot(a71$bias~a71$group|a71$cr*a71$g,type=c("l","g"),ylim=c(0,1),panel=mypanel)
plot(o1)
```

Comment: Would you be satisfied by changing all lines around the boxes? If so, adding `par.settings = list(box.rectangle = list(lwd = 2, col = "black"))` to `bwplot()` would do the trick.

Comment: @BenBarnes: yes this is perfect: it looks even better than the original!

Comment: If you want to try `ggplot2`, you can get a similar plot as follows: `ggplot(a71, aes(group, bias, fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot(fatten=3) +
  facet_grid(g ~ cr)`. `fatten` is what controls the median line thickness.

Comment: @eipi10: thanks for the hint but this is legacy code and I need to just update a plot for a review

Comment: @BenBarnes: can you post your solution as an answer? It fied my problem much better than anything I could find on the internet (or was hoping)? I would be glad to throw some reps your way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing some of the parameters of `box.rectangle` (a `lattice`-specific graphical parameter), you can manipulate the lines (including the median line) surrounding each of the box plots. This will change all the lines around the boxes, however, not just the median line.

```
myPars <- list(box.rectangle = list(lwd = 2, col = "black"))
```

`lwd` changes the line width (thickness). `col`changes the color of the lines. Then pass this list to the `par.settings` argument in `bwplot`.

```
o1 <- bwplot(a71$bias ~ a71$group | a71$cr * a71$g,
    type = c("l", "g"), ylim = c(0, 1), panel = mypanel,
    par.settings = myPars)
plot(o1)
```

To see all of the parameters associated with `box.rectangle`, use

```
trellis.par.get("box.rectangle")
```

Answer (score 1):

OP is happy with all lines thicker by @BenBarnes, but for completeness, it is possible to just thicken the median line.  Using the fact that `box.width` defaults to 1/2:

```
bwplot(a71$bias~a71$group|a71$cr*a71$g,type=c("l","g"),ylim=c(0,1),
      panel=function(x,y,...){
        panel.bwplot(x,y,...,pch="|",col="black",cex=4,fill=cl)
        medy <- by(y,list(x),median)
        xx <- sort(unique(as.numeric(x)))
        panel.segments(xx-.25,medy,xx+.25,medy,lwd=2)
      }
)
```